# Accord de deux adjectifs qui se suivent

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, participe-présent

Dans le cas où on a un nom qui est qualifié par un adjectif, on accorde l'adjectif avec le nom.  Mais que faire dans le cas où on qualifie l'adjectif qui qualifie le nom avec un autre adjectif ?

Spécifiquement, je pensais à un scénario comme celui-ci :

> C'est une personne catholique pratiquant[e].

Est-ce qu'il faudrait accorder le mot « pratiquant » avec « personne », ou reste-t-il invariable, vu qu'il prend le rôle d'un adverbe ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui te fait dire qu'il prend le rôle d'adverbe ?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, Il qualifie l'adjectif.

Comment: C'est débattable. Je comprends plutôt la phrase comme avec deux adjectifs : "*je suis catholique et pratiquant*". Comme on dit "*un catholique pratiquant*", j'ai tendance à voir *pratiquant* comme un adjectif même dans ta phrase. C'est ambigu justement parce que *catholique* peut être aussi bien nom qu'adjectif, mais je pense que c'est un peu un raccourci de dire qu'il est utilisé comme adverbe. J'ai regardé les adjectifs utilisés comme adverbe, ça ne ressemble pas vraiment à ça (plutôt : "ça sent **bon**")

Comment: Notice that if *pratiquant* were an adverb (it never is) it would necessarily come before the adjective.

Comment: @Telep, Alors, à ton avis, pratiquant serait accordé avec personne?

Comment: @Stéphane, good point.  Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: @anonymous2 Je ne suis pas très sûr de ma réponse, mais je l'accorderais avec la personne.

Comment: Personellement, je mettrais une conjonction. Une personne catholique et pratiquante. Je n'y vois aucun adverbe. Le style en français c'est d'éviter deux adjectifs l'un à la suite de l'autre (en général). Lá, ce n'est pas vraiment discutable.

Comment: Serait-il possible de changer le titre pour quelque chose qui se rapporte au sujet discuté ici. Il n'y a pas d'adjectif qui modifie des adjectifs en français (cf. les non-sens des grammaires traditionnelles sur les adjectifs de couleur)

Comment: @GAMPUB, voilà !

Comment: "Le style en français c'est d'éviter deux adjectifs l'un à la suite de l'autre (en général)" = source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une personne catholique pratiquante n'est pas la même chose qu'une personne catholique pratiquant.

Dans le second cas, "pratiquant" est un participe présent, une personne qui pratique régulièrement, qui est en train de pratiquer... pas un adjectif.

Une personne catholique pratiquante = même chose que sans le "personne" = C'est une catholique pratiquante.

Dans ce cas, on a "catholique" qui n'est plus adjectif, mais nom commun, et "pratiquante", qui reste adjectif.

-> Quand on dit une "personne catholique pratiquante", nous n'avons pas le mot "pratiquante" qui qualifie le mot "catholique", car il est impossible pour un adjectif d'en qualifier un autre: **un adjectif qualifie toujours un nom** (ou un mot pris comme nom).

**C'est la base de la définition de ce qu'est un adjectif.**

On ne pourrait dire *Ce petit chien jaune*, en pensant que "jaune" peut qualifier le mot "petit". Là c'est pareil!

- L'adjectif "catholique" se rapporte et qualifie le mot "personne", avec lequel il s'accorde en genre et en nombre.
- L'adjectif "pratiquante", se rapporte et qualifie également le mot "personne", avec lequel il s'accorde en genre et en nombre.

Qu'on ait "une personne pratiquante catholique" ou une "personne catholique pratiquante" ne change pas la grammaire, mais ne donne qu'un léger glissement de sens. Si j'ai "une pratiquante catholique", ici le mot "pratiquante" est un adjectif subtantivisé (transformé en nom), même chose pour "une catholique pratiquante", l'adjectif étant alors "pratiquante", dans mon second exemple.

Comment: Ce même type de raisonnement s'applique aux non-sens évoqués plus haut à propos des adjectifs de couleurs qui sont tous homophones avec des noms : *une robe verte* vs *une robe vert clair*. Dans le deuxième cas, *vert* est le nom de la couleur et *clair* qualifie le nom *vert*. Seuls les adjectifs peuvent être modifiés par très : *une robe ?très? vert clair* vs *une robe vert très clair*. => les adjectifs modifient des noms, mais certains noms modifient des noms, c'est un sujet bateau comme le *bleu marine*...

Comment: "Vert clair" est une entité à prendre comme un bloc, c'est le nom de la couleur, que le nom de la couleur se compose d'un seul mot ou de deux (on pourrait imaginer que ça s'écrive vert-clair) ne change rien. Pareil pour "bleu marine". "Marine" pourrait être un adjectif ou n'importe quoi (par exemple "vert bouteille"), un prénom, une ville, ou même un nombre.... ça n'a aucune incidence grammaticale, c'est en quelque sorte "grammaticalement inerte".

Comment: Marine est un nom dans ce cas d'où l'absence d'accord. Mais les adjectifs qui qualifient les couleurs s'accordent normalement...

Comment: ça ne change pas grand chose je pense, car les noms de couleurs composés sont invariables, qu'il s'agisse d'un nom ou d'un adjectif, c'est toujours une entité à prendre d'un "bloc".

Answer (score 0):

Je vois quatre possibilités et je vais mettre *pratiquant* à la forme négative pour illustrer mon idée (les deux premières me semblent correctes, les deux autres peut-être tirées par les cheveux) :

- *Catholique* et *pratiquante* sont des adjectifs de *personne* :

  > C'est une personne catholique non pratiquante.
- *Catholique* est l'adjectif de *personne* et *pratiquant* est un adverbe, on ne précise pas ce qui est pratiqué car c'est sous-entendu :

  > C'est une personne catholique ne pratiquant pas.
- *Catholique* est un nom et *pratiquant* est son adjectif :

  > C'est une personne catholique non pratiquant.
- *Personne*, *catholique* et *pratiquante* sont trois noms et *une* vaut pour les trois, auquel cas il s'agit forcément d'une femme puisque *pratiquant* doit être accordé avec *une* pour ne pas répéter l'article indéfini (bon, il faudrait des virgules, comme dans *c'est une femme, mère, épouse dévouée*)

Comment: Effectivement, c'est de même que ça me *paraissait* aussi, mais je n'avais pas des sources fiables pour y croire...

Comment: Attention à bien rester cohérent vis-à-vis de la grammaire. On ne peut pas dire que que "pratiquant" s'accorde avec "une". Un adjectif s'accorde toujours avec un nom, jamais avec autre chose. Dans la réponse donnée, l'exemple 2 et 3 relèvent de la même explication grammaticale. Catholique ne peut pas être un nom s'il suit le mot "personne", c'est forcément un adjectif décrivant "personne".

Comment: Sans doute, *pratiquant* n'est-il pas un adverbe mais un participe présent pour le point 2.